# Laravel - how to run the same PHP unit test n times to all start concurrently (testing for race conditions)

Tags: laravel, testing, transactions, phpunit

I am using a transaction accompanied by `updateOrCreate()`. As you can infer, things could go awry if multiple connections access and update the same id, a race condition in writing into the DB.

I am also locking that specific row that is being dealt with in my model.
My abbreviated code looks as follows in the file writing to the DB:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

DB::table('myTable')->where('my_id', $cells[0])->lockForUpdate()->get();

$outcome = Outcome::updateOrCreate([
    'my_id' => $cells[0]
    ],
    [
        'etc',$cells[1],
        'etc-etc',$cells[2],
    ]);

DB::commit();
```

> Please let me know if this is true: As far as I understood, I am getting a lock for that specific row
> so transaction n is on a queue awaiting transaction n - 1 to end, sequentially.

This test is supposed to simulate multiple requests, that are writing to the DB. Please let me know if more clarity is needed to answer this.
I would like to know how to test this. Do I run multiples of the same `TestCase`? If so, how? Or maybe there is another way to achieve this kind of concurrent test?

Comment: test cases are supposed to run separately so no to run the same test case multiple times.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond - which is exactly my question, how do I run `TestCase` n times concurrently and on seperate connections to the **same** DB.

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't answer that part but you probably have to spawn many processes to run the test.